# Is $\{x \in K^n | x_1x_5=1 \} \text{ a } K \text{-vector subspace of } K^n \text{?}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is $\{x \in K^n | x_1x_5=1 \} \text{ a } K \text{-vector subspace of } K^n \text{?}$

I think it is not because

$
 \left( \begin{array}{c}
5  \\
6  \\
7  \\
1  \\
\frac {1}{5}
\end{array} \right)
+
\left( \begin{array}{c}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
1 \\
\frac{1}{5}
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
10 \\
12 \\
14 \\
2 \\
\frac{4}{10}
\end{array} \right)
\
$ $\notin \{x \in K^n | x_1x_5=1 \}$

**Question**: Is that enough to show that the given set is not a $K$-vector subspace of $K^n$ or do I miss something here?

Comment: Does it contain 0?

Comment: No, it does not, I think. So $0$ is another argumentation that it is not a $K$-vector subspace?

Comment: Yes, your argument is valid. I think that checking for 0 is a faster easier way to see it though.

Comment: This argument works, except if $\text{char}(K) = 5$; in that case you need a different example. Checking for $(0,0,0,0,0)$ doesn't have this problem.